# How do I populate a React Formik form?

Tags: reactjs, formik

How do I populate a React Formik form? Like for e.g. to edit a record,  populate the existing data into the fields first.

I tried something like:

```
componentDidMount(){
   ...
   // get data from api call, 
   this.username = ...
   this.email = ...
}

render(){
  return(
    <Formik initialValues={{ username: this.username, email: this.email }}
  )
}
```

but the form always turns out empty. I guess that's also because render is called before componentDidMount. So how do I populate a Formik form?

Comment: See my other answer. Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62886732/1812371

Answer (score 16):

For this use case, you should set `enableReinitialize` on the form.

https://jaredpalmer.com/formik/docs/api/formik#enablereinitialize-boolean

> **enableReinitialize?**: boolean Default is false.
>
> Control whether Formik should reset the form if initialValues changes (using deep equality).

This will cause Formik to change any time a value in `initialValues` changes - You should take care to ensure the stability of the values within `initialValues` when enabling this.

Formik does use deep value equality to determine if there's a change, which means it will compare the value of fields within the object rather than the object reference itself to determine if there was a change.

---

You should store fields from a remote source in component state using `this.setState()` - setting the fields on the controller instance will prevent React from re-rendering in response to the field changes.

Comment: Can you explain this: "setting the fields on the controller instance will prevent React from re-rendering in response to the field changes."

Comment: React doesn't 'know' about the instance properties of a class component. If those change, React won't know to call the `render()` method again. That's why you have to use `setState()` in class components to trigger a re-render in response to local state changes.

Answer (score 4):

Set the response of your api call in your state, and in the render get the data from the state and it will work

```
componentDidMount(){
   ...
   // get data from api call, 
   this.setState({username: data.username, email: data.email})
}

render(){
  const {username, email} = this.state
  return(
    <Formik initialValues={{ username: username, email: email }}
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use setState

```
componentDidMount(){


   this.setState({
    username...
  })
}
```

so when the state is updated it will render the form with data

If you don't want to render the empty form then keep state weather data comes or not and show loader if it has not come yet

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try something like this:

```
...
function getData() {
  console.log("Called only once!");

  const userProfile: IProfile = {
    firstName: "First",
    lastName: "Last",
    email: "email@email.com"
  };

  return userProfile;
}

return (
  <Formik
    initialValues={getData()}
...
```

More here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-bhk3dn?file=index.tsx